# Unable to install visual studio, required .net framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install visual studio community 2015, however it has an error '.net framework required for setup'.
Tried installing .net framework 4.5.x, 4.6.x but it is stated that 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating system. You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4.5 redistributable.'

Comment: Do you have administrator access to the computer?

Comment: Yes as I'm the administrator of the system

Comment: Perhaps try the verification tool to see if there's any issues with the .NET installation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx

Comment: Checked and installed the missing 3.x 2.x .NET frames but still the same error persists.

Comment: What is your windows version ?

Comment: Windows 10 Professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**C++ redistributables were the source of problem,** as the .NET framework was verified using the tool mentioned above

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx

Check the C++ redistributables from this link and your are good to go

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003

As in my case *"Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update"* was missing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx does not exist anymore :(